# как найти фирму по программированию с базовыми знаниями , чтоб работать удаленно?

Tags: php

как найти фирму по программированию с базовыми знаниями , чтоб работать удаленно?

если допустим некоторые вещи не понимаю мне объясняют и я иду дальше, работая
мне подходит только удаленная . там где живу нет айти компаний

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что для поиска работы существуют совсем другие сайты.

Comment: *допустим некоторые вещи не понимаю мне объясняют и я иду дальше* Таких много. Только они денег не платят - наоборот, скорее ты им платить будешь. Это всякие школы-техникумы-институты. Не, вот ты реально думаешь, что кому-то нужен ТАКОЙ сотрудник?

Comment: К сожалению, это фантастика. Скорее можно найти удаленку, тебе дадут задание и ты будешь большую часть времени учиться сам, периодически посещая SO. Извини парень, но вопрос этот надо закрыть :)

Answer (score 3):

На рынке труда, как и в других рынках действует закон спроса и предложения. То есть требования работодателя складываются от следующих условий:

- От задач которые нужно решить
- От того, что может предложить рынок

И вот второй пункт для данного вопроса важен, php программистов много, так как php появился достаточно давно, php часто требуется на фриланс площадках и как следствие на рынке труда имеется большое количество php программистов с опытом. И начинающему php разработчику будет достаточно сложно конкурировать с опытными, но возможно в тех случаях, когда час работы начинающего разработчика будет намного дешевле опытного разработчика, и начинающий разработчик будет готов работать много часов.

Как правило для того, чтобы разработчик (особенно начинающий) начал делать первые задачи, ему нужно подсказывать и проверять, то есть в удаленном формате это будет дольше, а дольше значит дороже. То есть получается противоречие, с одной стороны начинающий разработчик дешевле (если посчитать оклад, разделив на часы), а с другой (если взять его удаленно) его контроль и обучение выходит дороже. Поэтому удаленно начинающих разработчиков очень редко берут.

Поэтому чтобы найти работу начинающему разработчику, скорее всего придется собрать список компаний где требуется php в его городе, ознакомиться с требованиями этих компаний, изучить их, и после этого отправлять резюме с готовностью работать полный день. А когда почувствуешь уверенность в своих знаниях, то попроситься на удаленку, или сменить работу на удаленную.